# Convergence of two-sided infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

By definition a two-sided series of complex numbers $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \alpha_n$ converges to a complex number $\alpha$ if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n$ and $\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} \alpha_n$ converge independently. Now I want to prove that this is equivalent to the statement that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\left| \sum_{n=-k}^{l} \alpha_n -\alpha\right| < \epsilon \qquad (\ast)$$

whenever $k,l \geq N$.

The if and only if-direction follows rather directly from the definition since we only have to choose $N=\max{(N_1,N_2)}$ where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are the respective thresholds for the one-sided series. However I'm stuck with the if-direction. When assuming $(\ast)$ how can I arrive at the conditions for the respective one-sided series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $N \in \Bbb N$
such that $(*)$ holds for all $k, l \ge N$
then in particular for $m >l  \ge N$
$$
 \sum_{n=l+1}^{m} \alpha_n 
 = \left( \sum_{n=-N}^{m} \alpha_n - \alpha \right) - \left( \sum_{n=-N}^{l} \alpha_n - \alpha \right)
$$
and therefore
$$
 \left| \sum_{n=l+1}^{m} \alpha_n\right|  \le 2 \epsilon \, .
$$
This shows that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_n$ is convergent
because of [Cauchy's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test)
for infinite series.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes one can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: @JakobElias: You are welcome! – The point is that we can only prove convergence of the one-series series, but not determine its value. That suggests using the Cauchy criterion.